# Laravel Manual Update Timestamp

Tags: laravel

I have a miscellaneous database table that is updated each time a user visits another user's profile. I'm having trouble creating a manual timestamp column though. Since I didn't create a model for this, I'm doing it manually which shouldn't be an issue because this database isn't accepting any user-generated input.

Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recently_visited', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('visitor_id');
        $table->integer('profile_id');
        $table->integer('times_visited');
        $table->timestamp('last_visit');
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
$visits = DB::table('recently_visited')
    ->where('profile_id',$user->id)
    ->where('visitor_id',Auth::user()->id)
    ->increment('times_visited')
    ->update(array('last_visit' => Carbon::now()));
```

I get the following error. Please help me understand, what is the integer this is being called on. Thanks!

Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on integer

ANSWER:

I just needed to include all my updated within the increment() in the query builder.

```
$visits = DB::table('recently_visited')
    ->where('profile_id',$user->id)
    ->where('visitor_id',Auth::user()->id)
    ->increment('times_visited', 1, ['last_visit' => Carbon::now()]);
```

Comment: `Carbon::now()` is not a timestamp instance. So, try  `->update(array('last_visit' => Carbon::now()->timestamp));` and let me know if you have any other error.

Comment: Still shows the same error.

Comment: Its with the `increment()` call. So you should do it in the update method along with the timestamp update.

Comment: Could you update with the question with the correct query for future visitors?

Comment: Done! Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Please help me understand, what is the integer this is being called on.*

[`increment()`](https://github.com/pmatseykanets/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1811) method doesn't return query builder instance but rather updates the record itself and returns an integer.

You should be able to do this:

```php
$visits = DB::table('recently_visited')
    ->where('profile_id',$user->id)
    ->where('visitor_id',Auth::user()->id)
    ->increment('times_visited', 1, array('last_visit' => Carbon::now()));
```

Comment: Ok, that works. I wasn't quite understanding the documentation on using increment() in the query builder, but got it now. Much appreciated.

->increment('times_visited', 1, ['last_visit' => Carbon::now()]);